# Installing mysql2 gem rails on mac

Tags: ruby, rubygems, mysql2

I am trying to do gem install of mysql2 but it looks like it is not finding where mysql is installed. I installed mysql using the XAMPP stack on my mac. I read other post but yield to no results.

```
sudo  gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-config=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql_config 
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-mysql-config=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql_config
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... no
checking for mysql.h... no
checking for mysql/mysql.h... no
-----
mysql.h is missing.  please check your installation of mysql and try again.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
    --with-mysql-config


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.11 for inspe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While building native extensions, `gem` is looking for mysql headers. These might be in `/Application/XAMPP/...` and you could point to them via the following args to `gem` -

```
--with-mysql-dir=/path/to/mysql \
--with-mysql-include=/path/to/mysql/headers \
--with-mysql-lib=/path/to/lib \
--with-mysql-config=/path/to/configs
```

Alternatively, if using the XAMPP's mysql isn't necessary, you could get mysql via [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and then -

```
brew install mysql 
gem install mysql2
```

I would prefer the second way. It's cleaner and less confusing as I do not know what changes XAMPP makes to their bundled mysql ;)

Later if you need to setup such gems on a linux vps, and encounter similar issues, remember to install the `-dev` packages. E.g. `libmysqlclient-dev` for mysql.

Comment: I would do the brew install but I am just wondering whether it might conflict with my existing installation of XAMPP's mysql

Comment: XAMPP's mysql instance comes up only when you run it. So if you quit it, it shouldn't conflict with brew's mysql. To make both of them run together, you could alter ports of XAMPP one. Also, do take a look at instructions after you `brew install mysql`. It points to infos like - how to start, stop and run mysql automatically post boot.